# SPARQL regex doesn't match Persian characters with the "i" flag

Tags: regex, sparql, virtuoso, persian

I expect the ignore case "i" flag to only increase the amount of matches, not to decrease them, but the following SPARQL query (endpoint http://www.snik.eu/sparql) does result in one match without the flag but no matches with it:

`select * { ?s rdfs:label ?l. filter(regex(str(?l),"قانون بیمارستان")) }`

-> 1 match

`select * { ?s rdfs:label ?l. filter(regex(str(?l),"قانون بیمارستان","i")) }`

-> no match

With non-Persian letters it works as expected:

`select count(*) { ?s rdfs:label ?l.filter(regex(str(?l),"Information"))`}

-> 319 matches

`select count(*) { ?s rdfs:label ?l.filter(regex(str(?l),"Information","i"))`}

-> 363 matches

What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I change it to behave as expected?

Virtuoso version 07.20.3217 on Linux (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu), Single Server Edition

P.S.:
The problem still persists after an upgrade to 07.20.3229.

The problem also occurs on DBpedia, which has the same version right now:

```
select *
{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Persian_language> dbo:abstract ?l.    
  filter(regex(str(?l),"فارسی","i")).
}
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your query for https://query.wikidata.org and try it with `FILTER(!CONTAINS(?name, "قانون بیمارستان"))`. Similar queries with this filter work for me.

Comment: Without `str()`, it works. I. e. `filter(regex(?l, "قانون بیمارستان", "i"))`.

Comment: snik.eu should be [encouraged to upgrade](http://www.snik.eu/de/Site/Kontakt/index.jsp) from that June 2017 build of VOS 7.2.4. There are a number of Unicode- and i18n-related fixes in the current `stable/7` 7.2.5.1 and `develop/7` 7.2.6-rc1, which may resolve this.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi This alternative gives correct results on my endpoint if I add an LCASE for case insensitive matching.

Comment: @TallTed: We will upgrade to 7.2.5.1, thanks!

Comment: @StanislavKralin Interesting! Is there any downside to not using the str function in this case?

Comment: *Is there any downside* — I don't think so. According to the specs, `REGEX` accepts string literals (not only simple literals) as its first argument.

Comment: @TallTed We upgraded to 7.2.5.1 now but the problem still persists. Also, the version is reported as "07.20.3229", is this correct?

Comment: @KonradHöffner - Yes, `7.2.5.1` is a product version; `07.20.3229` is an engine version. Thank you for following up on the [github issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/705)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an open issue on the Virtuoso GitHub repository regarding this problem at https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/705, it seems to be under investigation.

Thanks to all the commenters for helping with the investigation and for giving great workarounds and alternatives.